# Enqueue a file that's not js or css

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, admin-css

I want to register a new css document that I'm storing inside a PHP file (so that I can create variable css rules). I tried doing this:

```
function tps_admin_scripts() {
$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
wp_register_script('admin-variable-style', $plugin_url.'css/style-variable.php');
wp_enqueue_script('admin-variable-style');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'tps_admin_scripts');
```

And I've also tried wp_enqueue_style with no luck.

Additionally, I tried

```
require_once (plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'css/style-variable.php');
```

But that simply rendered the raw style/html onto the page.

Inside the .php file, I have something like this:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
<?php
//Calendar Color Pickers
$tpsSettings = get_option( 'tps_rental_settings' );
?>

.colorAvailable {
    background-color: <?php echo $tpsSettings['tps_calendar_color_available']; ?>
}
```

Is this possible to do with WP? If not, any other solutions to including a php file to run as an additional css file?

Answer (score 1):

You could also look to create a special CSS file that you setup an htaccess rewrite rule for. For example

`wp-content/yourtheme/custom.css`

And then add a rule in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/yourtheme/custom.css$ /wp-content/yourtheme/styles.php [L]
```

You can then call wp-load inside this `styles.php` file, do any sort of logic required, before outputting your custom css rules:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>
p {
   color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perhaps a cleaner solution from a themeing perspective!

Answer (score 0):

That answer was to put this in my php file:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
```